# Unable to run Play framework app in Alpine-based Docker container

Tags: docker, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I have a Play app that runs on the default (as provided by sbt) docker base image. I would like to switch this app to an Alpine-based image.

Per [sbt-native-packager docs](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html#busybox-ash-support), I added

```
enablePlugins(AshScriptPlugin)
dockerBaseImage := "openjdk:8-jre-alpine"
```

to my `build.sbt` file. When I try to run this container, I get the following errors:

```
bin/foo-service: line 51: /opt/docker/lib/foo-service.foo-service-1.0.40-launcher.jar: Permission denied
bin/foo-service: line 56: is_cygwin: not found
Unrecognized option: -J-Xms512M
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is already an issue tracking this. The issue is due to play adding some non-ash compliant stuff to the bash script extras.

https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/1118

One workaround suggested (https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/978#issuecomment-313393423) is to add this to your `build.sbt`

```
bashScriptExtraDefines := List(
    """addJava "-Duser.dir=$(realpath "$(cd "${app_home}/.."; pwd -P)")""""
)
```